# Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 451 Temporary local problem - please try later: retry timeout exceeded

Tags: email, dns, centos

so the problem is that email accounts that are connected with a domain do not work. Nor sending or receiving.

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  receiver@email.com
    host web.com 
    SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<receiver@email.com>:
    451 Temporary local problem - please try later:
    retry timeout exceeded


Reporting-MTA: dns; relay1.stackmail.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;receiver@email.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; web.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 451 Temporary local problem - please try later: retry timeout exceeded
```

I have tried to put a DNS TXT record with `SPF v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` than i have checked if the domain was blacklisted. Then I have tried to update ClamAV. That also did not help.
Also I cannot check on the [mail-tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) because the emails do not send or receive emails. Domain site is online and live. I first thought that it has something to do with the DNS settings.
Domain is from one provider, while hosting is on another provider. Not sure where to look, i have spent 5 hours trying to find out what happened. I have upgraded the PHP version before that problem, could that be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

To update, this issue was solved by running the following command:

Code:
/scripts/mailperm
This repopulated some missing domain names in the /etc/localdomains file.